# Homogeneous Function Exchange of Variable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a homogeneous function of degree 1 such that $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \ \  f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$

Can I do the following?
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} y f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(yx) = \frac{d}{dx} f(y)x = f(y) 
\end{align}

In particular, can I obtain this result from Euler's theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correct to me. For example if
$$
f(x)=kx
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}yf(x)=\frac{d}{dx}ykx=ky=f(y)
$$
Euler theorem in this case can be expressed as
$$
x\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x)
$$
and it can be applied to $yf(x),$ being itself homogeneous, so
$$
x\frac{d}{dx}yf(x)=yf(x)=xf(y),\ \forall x\quad\implies\quad \frac{d}{dx}yf(x)=f(y)
$$